# How to sum a grouped column in AREL

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

in Rails 3/AREL

`Model.group(:label).sum(:value)` will do

```
SELECT sum(value), label from model_table group by label
```

I am trying to find the AREL way of doing

```
SELECT sum(value) from (select value, label from model_table group by label)
```

which is `Model.group(:label).map(&:value).sum` using ruby to sum, how do I do this in SQL/AREL

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this makes sense. Your core SQL is not valid:

```
SELECT value, label FROM model_table GROUP BY label
```

You cannot have a GROUP BY without an aggregation function (e.g. SUM) in your select. I think what you actually want is this:

```
SELECT label, SUM(value) from model_table GROUP BY label
```

Am I right? To do this in AREL, try this:

```
relation = Model.select(:label).
  select(Model.arel_table[:value].sum.as("value_sum")).
  group(:label)
relation.to_sql
# => SELECT label, SUM("model_table"."impressions") AS value_sum FROM "model_table" GROUP BY label
```

Comment: How do you access `value_sum`? When I try to do `relation.first.value_sum` I get `NoMethodError: undefined method` for `value_sum`.