# Report using Rails ActiveRecord group by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am trying to generate a report to screen of accounting transaction history. In most situations it is one display row per record in the `AccountingTransaction` table. But occasionally there are transactions that I wish to display to the end user as one transaction which are really, behind the scenes, two accounting transactions. This is caused by deferral of revenues and fund splitting since this app is a fund accounting app.

If I display all rows one by one, those double entries look odd to the user since the fund splitting and deferral is "behind the scenes". So I want to roll up all the related transactions into one display row on screen.

I have my query now using group by to group the related transactions

```
@history = AccountingTransaction.where("customer_id in (?) AND no_download <> 1", customers_in_account).group(:transaction_type_id, :reference_id).order(:created_at)
```

as I loop through I get the transactions grouped as I want but I am struggling with how to display the total sum of the 'credit' field for all records in the group. (It is only showing the credit for the first record of the group) If I add a `.sum(:credit)` to my query, of course, it returns the sums just as I want but not all the other data.

Is there a way for me to group these records like in my `@history` query and also get the sum of the credit field for each respective group?

* Addition ***
What I really want is what the following SQL query would give me.

```
    SELECT transaction_type_id, reference_id, sum(credit) 
WHERE customer_id in (21,22,23,24) AND no_download <> 1 
GROUP BY reference_id, transaction_type_id ORDER BY created_at
```

Comment: I'm sure you could use AREL, like discribed in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5972336/how-to-sum-a-grouped-column-in-arel

Comment: That looks like it might work. I haven't used AREL before so I'll have to dig into it a bit. I tried what the poster suggests in that post you linked to but it won't assign anything to the variable when I test it in the console. I must be missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure you can do "ORDER BY created_at" and not include it in the select fields, but here is an example.

```
@history = AccountingTransaction.
  select([:reference_id, :transaction_type_id, :created_at]).
  select(AccountingTransaction.arel_table[:credit].sum.as("credit_sum")).
  where("customer_id in (?) AND no_download <> 1", customers_in_account).
  group(:transaction_type_id, :reference_id).
  order(:created_at)
```

To access the credit_sum you could do:

```
@history[0].attributes["credit_sum"]
```

I guess if you'd like, you could create a method:

```
def credit_sum
  attributes["credit_sum"]
end
```

- EDIT *

As stated in comments you can access the attribute directly:

```
@history[0].credit_sum
```

Comment: Excellent, that was pretty much it! I had to make a few changes to make it work. I changed `:customer_id` to `:reference_id` since a `GROUP BY` element must be in the select list and also added `:created_at` to the select list since, as you mentioned, an `ORDER BY` element must also be in the select list. Then there are missing brackets in the first multi attribute select list -- it needs to be `select([:reference_id, :transaction_type_id, :created_at])`. Outside of those changes it worked beautifully. Appreciated!

Comment: This is why I love stackoverflow.com! Great job Magness. One last thing. I was able to access credit_sum by simply using `h.credit_sum` as I looped through `@history.each do |h|` in Rails 3.2.